# Custom alert presenting over empty window instead of previous viewController

Tags: swift

As you can see I am setting the presentation style as `.overCurrentContext`.

```
 extension SingleQuestionViewController: AddResponseDelegate {

  func save(response text: String, questionID: Int) {
    questionsWrapper.add(newResponse: text, questionID: questionID) { [weak self] successful in
        if successful {
            self?.responseTV?.safelyReload()
        } else {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                let alertViewController = AlertViewController<Any>()
                alertViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
                let contentModel = RegularContentsModel(title: "controllerTitle", message: "message")

                let authorizeButtonModel = SimpleButtonModel(title: "yes message", action: {
                    //action goes here
                })

                let doNothingButtonModel = SimpleButtonModel(title: "noMsg", action: {
                    //completion?()
                })

                alertViewController.styleRegular(regularContentsModel: contentModel,
                                                 models: [authorizeButtonModel, doNothingButtonModel])

                self?.present(alertViewController, animated: false, completion: nil)
            }
        }
    }
    questionsWrapper.goToQuestion(with: questionID)
    responseTV?.safelyReload()
  }
}
```

Here is the result:

[image]

I don't think this is caused by it being on the background thread, because if I move it to viewDidLoad, then I get the same result:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setUpTopBar()
        setupSearchBar()
        responseTV.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
        setupArrows()
        responseTV.register(SimpleCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: SimpleCell.reuseID)
        setAccessibility()        
        let alertViewController = AlertViewController<Any>()
        alertViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
        let contentModel = RegularContentsModel(title: "controllerTitle", message: "message")

        let authorizeButtonModel = SimpleButtonModel(title: "yes message", action: {
            //action goes here
        })

        let doNothingButtonModel = SimpleButtonModel(title: "noMsg", action: {
            //completion?()
        })

        alertViewController.styleRegular(regularContentsModel: contentModel,
                                         models: [authorizeButtonModel, doNothingButtonModel])

        self.present(alertViewController, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }
```

Here is the implementation of my custom alert.

```
class AlertViewController<Payload>: AkinVC {

  typealias FlagsAction = ([ReportFlag], Payload) -> Void

  enum AlertStyle<Payload> {
    case flag(FlagsAction)
  }

  let innerWholeAlertContainer = UIView() 
  let outerWholeAlertContainer = UIView()


  let buttonStack = AlertButtonsStack()
  var payload: Payload?
  let transitionDuration: TimeInterval = 0.11
  let containerWidth: CGFloat = 300

  private var contentsView: UIView! {
    didSet {
        innerWholeAlertContainer.addSubview(contentsView)
        contentsView.constraints(firstHorizontal: .distanceToLeading(innerWholeAlertContainer.leadingAnchor, 0),
                                 secondHorizontal: .distanceToTrailing(innerWholeAlertContainer.trailingAnchor, 0),
                                 vertical: .distanceToTop(innerWholeAlertContainer.topAnchor, 0),
                                 secondVertical: .distanceToBottom(buttonStack.topAnchor, 0))
      }
  }

  func styleNoButtons(regularContentsModel: RegularContentsModel) {
    initialSetup()
    let alertContentView = RegularContentsView()
    alertContentView.model = regularContentsModel.forContainer(width: containerWidth)
    contentsView = alertContentView
    setButtonConstraints()
  }

  func styleAsFlagView(flagsAction: @escaping FlagsAction) {

    initialSetup()
    let stackView = FlagsStackView()
    stackView.flagItemViews = [FlagItemView](ReportFlag.allCases)
    contentsView = stackView

    buttonStack.buttonModels(
        ButtonModel(tekt: "Report", color: .romanceRed, tektColor: .white, action: { [weak stackView] in
            guard let selectedFlags = stackView?.flagItemViews?.selectedFlags,
                let payload = self.payload else { return }
            flagsAction(selectedFlags, payload)
            self.dismissAlert()
        }),
        ButtonModel(tekt: "Cancel", color: .white, tektColor: .black,
                    borders: BorderModel(color: UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.16), width: 1, edges: [.top]),
            action: { [weak self] in
            self?.dismissAlert()
        })
    )
    setButtonConstraints()
  }

  func styleAsOkayAlert(regularContentsModel: RegularContentsModel, action: Action? = nil) {
    initialSetup()
    let alertContentView = RegularContentsView()
    alertContentView.model = regularContentsModel.forContainer(width: containerWidth)
    contentsView = alertContentView

    let okayModel = standardizeButtonsWithDismissAction(models: [SimpleButtonModel(title: "Okay, I got it.", action: action)])
    buttonStack.buttonModels(okayModel)
    setButtonConstraints()
  }

  func styleCancelAlert(regularContentsModel: RegularContentsModel, models: SimpleButtonModel...) {
    initialSetup()
    let alertContentView = RegularContentsView()
    alertContentView.model = regularContentsModel.forContainer(width: containerWidth)
    contentsView = alertContentView

    var models = models
    models.append(SimpleButtonModel(title: "Cancel"))
    let newButtonModels = standardizeButtonsWithDismissAction(models: models)
    buttonStack.buttonModels(newButtonModels)
    setButtonConstraints()
  }

func styleRegular(regularContentsModel: RegularContentsModel, models: SimpleButtonModel...) {
    self.styleRegular(regularContentsModel: regularContentsModel, models: models)
  }

  func styleRegular(regularContentsModel: RegularContentsModel, models: [SimpleButtonModel]) {
    initialSetup()

    let alertContentView = RegularContentsView()
    alertContentView.model = regularContentsModel.forContainer(width: containerWidth)
    contentsView = alertContentView

    let newButtonModels = standardizeButtonsWithDismissAction(models: models)
    buttonStack.buttonModels(newButtonModels)
    setButtonConstraints()
  }

  private func standardizeButtonsWithDismissAction(models: [SimpleButtonModel]) -> [ButtonModel] {
    var buttonModelsToAdd: [ButtonModel] = []
    let count = models.count
    for (inde, model) in models.enumerated() {
        var borders: [BorderModel] = []
        if count > 2 || count == 1 {
            borders.append(BorderModel(color: .lightGray, width: 1, edges: [.top]))
        } else if count == 2 {
            if inde == 0 {
                borders.append(BorderModel(color: .lightGray, width: 1, edges: [.top]))
            } else if inde == 1 {
                borders.append(BorderModel(color: .lightGray, width: 1, edges: [.left, .top]))
            }
        }
        buttonModelsToAdd.append(ButtonModel(tekt: model.title, color: .white, tektColor: .darkGray, borders: borders, action: {
            model.action?()
            self.dismissAlert()
        }))
    }
    return buttonModelsToAdd
  }

  func dismissAlert() {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: transitionDuration, animations: {
        self.view.alpha = 0
    }) { (completed) in
        self.safelyDissmiss(animated: false)
    }
  }


  fileprivate func initialSetup() {
    self.view.alpha = 0
    modalPresentationStyle = .currentContext
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.3)
    view.addSubview(outerWholeAlertContainer)
    outerWholeAlertContainer.addSubview(innerWholeAlertContainer)
    outerWholeAlertContainer.pinToEdges(innerWholeAlertContainer)
    innerWholeAlertContainer.backgroundColor = .white
    innerWholeAlertContainer.addSubview(buttonStack)
    outerWholeAlertContainer.constraints(.horizontal(.centeredHorizontallyWith(view)),
                                         .vertical(.centeredVerticallyTo(view)),
                                         .horizontal(.width(containerWidth)) )
  }

func setButtonConstraints() {
    buttonStack.constraints(.horizontal(.distanceToLeading(innerWholeAlertContainer.leadingAnchor, 0)),
                            .horizontal(.distanceToTrailing(innerWholeAlertContainer.trailingAnchor, 0)),
                            .vertical(.distanceToBottom(innerWholeAlertContainer.bottomAnchor, 0)))
  }

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    outerWholeAlertContainer.layer.applySketchShadow()
    innerWholeAlertContainer.roundCorners(constant: 15)
    UIView.animate(withDuration: transitionDuration, animations: {
        self.view.alpha = 1
    })
  }
}
```

Here is what the visual debugger shows:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hard to help without any details about the implementation of your custom alert.

Comment: Wouldn't it be rather important to say when/where you are running the `DispatchQueue.main.async` code you show at the start? Show what method we are in. Explain how it gets called. Show what `self` is. And so on. The fact that you are having to do with in a `main.async` call suggests that this is happening in a background thread, and that is a red flag right there.

Comment: @rmaddy, I added the implementation details of the custom alert.

Comment: And @matt, I added the details you requested.  The use case for the background thread is when there is an erroneous result returned from the server.

Comment: Whenever I have these types of problems, I rely heavily on the visual debugger.  There could be a frame that you are inadvertently building that's the entire size of the screen (The black background part).

Comment: @LorenRogers, doing so shows that it totally is doing away with my `SingleQuestionViewController`.  Let me add that to my question.  Which is weird because I am setting the `modalPresentationStyle` as `.overCurrentContext`

Comment: @ScottyBlades I'm not trying to insult your intelligence, but are you sure you've viewed the entire hierarchy on the left hand side of XCode while broken in visual debugger?

Comment: Insult away, my friend. :) I come here in full acceptance of my shortcomings.  If I'm missing something, please let me know.  Just trying to do my best. If I'm misunderstanding, please don't hesitate to point it out.  @LorenRogers, I've pasted what I understand to be the full hierarchy list.  I don't think SingleQuestionViewController's view is there.

Comment: OK, you understand, yes, that your lines `questionsWrapper.goToQuestion(with: questionID); responseTV?.safelyReload()` are getting executed _before_ the alert has a chance to appear? I mean it is very unusual to have _any_ code _after_ async code, and if you are trying to navigate somewhere else from SingleQuestionViewController before the alert even gets a chance to be presented from SingleQuestionViewController, that could have something to do with the situation.

Comment: @matt, When I move it to `viewdidload` and omit the lines you mention, I get the same result.  I added that to the question above.  I think if lines of code are placed after Dispatching to the main thread, then they just run before the Session returns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The view controller:

- creates the alert controller;
- sets `modalPresentationStyle` to `.overCurrentContext`; and
- and calls `styleRegular`.

But `styleRegular`:

- calls `initialSetup`
- which resets `modalPresentationStyle` to `.currentContext`

It's that last step that is discarding your previous `.overCurrentContext` setting.

Comment: I want to add that while that was the answer, the other problem I had was that I was setting the `modalPresentationStyle` property too late.  I have now found it best to create an initializer like this: